# Opening older Numbers files

Tags: macos, numbers

I am running Monterey, with Numbers version 11.2. I have some old spreadsheets that I created in Numbers circa 2011. I tried to open them and received the error message: "[filename].numbers can't be opened right now. Numbers couldn't read the file." It can't be read with QuickLook either.

I'm recalling something now about recent versions of Numbers being incompatible with old versions of the files (wtf, Apple?) But I do still want to be able to read the old version that I trusted Apple's software to create and am no longer able to - how can I do that?

Comment: Numbers 11 should still be able to open Numbers '09 projects (which 2011 would be). It seems like they're corrupt, not just outdated.

Comment: Is it possible that those files were created using a version of Numbers older than Numbers '09 which was launched in 2009? If so, here is [a guide](https://www.macworld.com/article/234285/how-to-open-ancient-pages-numbers-and-keynote-documents-in-macos.html) that might be helpful. If not, then they are probably corrupt as @Ezekiel says.

Comment: Now that I look back at it, they would have been last updated in 2011 but created in 2009, and probably not on the latest version. In part because it's multiple files all having this problem, I suspect these are the pre-2009 Numbers. And the guide Alper linked to says it won't work on anything after Catalina (such as Monterey).